# is it possible to export XML data from a swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

Is it possible to export XML data from a SWF file?

Comment: What do you mean by export? Do you want the users to download some XML? That can definitely be done.

Comment: he was mean to send XML data, to server-side. Like POST query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rickydoesit.com/actionscript-3/how-to-connect-to-php-with-actionscript-3-and-post-variables-to-php/

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/mysql_xml_asp_03.html

http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_9/article_442-post-request-data-in-as3.htm

let us know your server-side etc.

instead of simple variables you could put your xml data.

Comment: i mean that 
i made a flash game 
and i want the score of the game export  as xml data 
to read it in my php file

Comment: aha, you need URLLoader and PHP CRUD interface to store all this things into MySQL or etcSQL DB.

Comment: i've them 
i want to know how i can link between the flash data (score )and the php